# Make JButton clickable instead of JLabel

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jlabel, actionlistener

I have a case where I put the JLabel inside JButton and adapts the JButton size.

The issue here is everytime I click the button, the JLabel catches most of the events.

When I tried to add ActionListener to the JButton, it didn't work.

But when I tried to add MouseListener to JLabel, all the event handlers work.

I want the ActionListener for the JButton to work. I don't want the JLabel to catches all of the events without destroying my default configuration on them.

I tried setting the JLabel focusable property to false but it didn't work also.

So what should I do then?

Comment: Why do you need a label in a button?

Comment: You can call `setText` on a `JButton`, which lets you do pretty much anything you could do with a label. Why do you need the label?

Comment: To get rid of the box surrounding the text when clicking the button and for ui modifications

Comment: You try using JButton#setBorderPainted and JButton#setFocusPaonted and JButton#setContentAreaFilled to see of they help

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I have other plans :D I will note about this.

Comment: _I put the JLabel inside JButton_ while possible, that's **wrong** - a button is not designed to be used as a container. So you need veeery good reasons to break that rule (and will run in more problems than you expect) In view of that, your question is upside down as well as incomplete: you assume a solution to a goal you didn't state and have problems with that assumed solution ...

Comment: I'm not actually able to reproduce the problem. I tried putting a JLabel, and even a JPanel, inside a JButton, but the button still worked perfectly. Clicking on the obscured parts still dispatched the event to the underlying button. That suggests to me this really isn't something you should be doing, if it's so finicky.

Answer (score 2):

> I have a case where I put the JLabel inside JButton and adapts the
>   JButton size.

this is basic property, by default top layed `JComponent` consume all events came from `Mouse` & `Keyboard`

there are two ways

- (no idea why is there `JLabel`) if is possible to use plain `JButton` with implemented methods in API instead
- add `MouseListener` (maybe there no reason to override all `MouseEvents` add only `MouseAdapter`) to `JLabel` and from `mouseClicked` to call `JButton.doClick()`

EDIT

@Mad,

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;

public class JButtonAndIcon {

    private JLabel label = new JLabel();
    private Random random = new Random();
    private ImageIcon image1; // returns null don't worry about in Swing
    private ImageIcon image2; // returns null don't worry about in Swing
    private Timer backTtimer;
    private int HEIGHT = 300, WEIGHT = 200;


    public JButtonAndIcon() {
        label.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(HEIGHT, WEIGHT));
        final JButton button = new JButton("Push");
        button.setBorderPainted(false);
        button.setBorder(null);
        button.setFocusable(false);
        button.setMargin(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
        button.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        button.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        button.add(label);
        button.setMultiClickThreshhold(1000);
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (button.getIcon() == image1) {
                    label.setIcon(image2);
                } else {
                    label.setIcon(image1);
                    if(backTtimer.isRunning()){
                         backTtimer.restart();
                    }                   
                }
            }
        });
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.add(button);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        startBackground();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JButtonAndIcon t = new JButtonAndIcon();
            }
        });
    }

    private void startBackground() {
        backTtimer = new javax.swing.Timer(1500, updateBackground());
        backTtimer.start();
        backTtimer.setRepeats(true);
    }

    private Action updateBackground() {
        return new AbstractAction("Background action") {

            private final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getImage()));
            }
        };
    }

    public BufferedImage getImage() {
        int w = label.getWidth();
        int h = label.getHeight();
        GradientPaint gp = new GradientPaint(0f, 0f, new Color(
                127 + random.nextInt(128),
                127 + random.nextInt(128),
                127 + random.nextInt(128)),
                w, w,
                new Color(random.nextInt(128), random.nextInt(128), random.nextInt(128)));
        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics2D g2d = bi.createGraphics();
        g2d.setPaint(gp);
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        return bi;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this only be the case if 1- the label had listeners registered (or a tooltip) and 2- was opaque

Comment: @MadProgrammer by default (if is used LayoutManager) there isn't any issue, see my edit, all events are registred, dispathed as for plain JButton, I'm too lazy to ask for effort by OP.....